# **/*.java not working as argument to Bash script

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I have a simple bash script file named: test.sh.

```
#!/bin/bash

ls $1;
```

I gave the execution permissions:

```
$ ./test.sh "**/*.java" 
shows only one file
```

where as

```
$ ls **/*.java
shows hundreds of files
```

So how to make the script work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable support for `**` in Bash, use the `globstar` option:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar

ls $1
```

(See [§4.3.2 "The Shopt Builtin" in the *Bash Reference Manual*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Shopt-Builtin).)

Comment: I missed that. Is it possible to use #!/bin/zsh instead of bash and avoid shopt command

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi: Yes.